# Android custom listview multiline with header sections

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to set my layout like the [contacts](http://cdn.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/2011-10-19-13h39_40.png) app, here is my app layout:

[image]

I have 2 listviews, one for phones, and another one for emails, I want to set a header for eachone of them, just like the contacts app. Can someone guide me on how would I do that?

the xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, World"
            style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"

            >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, Universe"
            android:layout_above="@+id/listView2"
            style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listView1"
            >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contato_details);

        Bundle parametros = getIntent().getExtras();

        tele = (ArrayList<ContatosTelefoneModel>) parametros.get("tel");
        email = (ArrayList<ContatosEmailModel>) parametros.get("email");


        ListView b = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        b.setHeaderDividersEnabled(true);
        b.setAdapter(new TelefoneListAdapter(this, tele));


        ListView e = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        e.setHeaderDividersEnabled(true);
        e.setAdapter(new EmailListAdapter(this, email));



    }
```

Comment: y do u wanna use two list views

Comment: Because I have 2 adapters, I'm getting this information from a Json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you given image they have use `StickyListHeaders` that you can find here

https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

and top of the image you see that  is tab that you can find here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cu6kauu6vhsss45/tabcarousellib.rar